# MLE for geometric series

Tags: probability

I was trying to get the MLE for the geometric series, but I didn't get the right answer. Basically, I got: $p^n(1-p)^{n(k-1)}$ I think this is where I made a mistake and basically I ended with:

$p$ = $\frac{-n}{-2n+nk}$

the answer is:

1/Xbar

When you multiply $(1-p)^{(k-1)}$ n times shouldn't you get $(1-p)^{n(k-1)}$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't multiplying $(1-p)^{(k-1)}$ $n$ times. You are multiplying

$$
\prod_{i=1}^n (1-p)^{x_i-1}p
$$

so the $k$ depends on $i$.

Comment: is it E(k-1) or E(k)-1?

Comment: The exponent is $x_i - 1$.